# Unwanted wrapped results for operations on numpy array subclass

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand the details of [Subclassing ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) - but it's very dense. (Second possibility: I'm dense.)

Here's a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, foo='foo'):
        self = input_array.view(cls)
        self.foo = foo
        return self

    def __array_finalize__(self, from_array):
        if from_array is not None:
            self.foo = getattr(from_array, 'foo', 'foo')
```

Here's a demo of the unwanted behavior:

```
>>> a = MyArray(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
>>> a
MyArray([[0, 1, 2],
         [3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8]])
>>> 
>>> a.foo
'foo'
>>> a.sum()
MyArray(36)
>>> np.sum(a)
MyArray(36)
>>> print(a.sum())
36 # interesting
>>> a.sum().shape
()
```

How can I prevent functions or methods that are supposed to return a single number from wrapping the result in a `MyArray`?

Answer (score 2):

This is hard one. All I could come up with is 2 solutions and I dont like any of it - One  from numpy documentation on subclassing ndarray - using array_wrap. Second is more save -> **override** np.sum and other funcs you desire.

**NOTE:**

The below code **needs to be polished**, mainly the solution with **array_wrap**. However it looks that **array_wrap** is the correct direction as it works on other functions too (*.mean() etc.) But as you said, documentation is dense, and its hard to say what are the consequences hacking these magic functions.
Overriding is on the other side straightforward and clean, but who wants to override every existing function?

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, foo='foo'):
        self = input_array.view(cls)
        self.foo = foo
        return self

    # First solution - define this func that is magically called on results (check documentation)
    def __array_wrap__(self, out_arr, context=None):
       if not out_arr.shape:
           out_arr = out_arr.reshape(-1)[0] 
           # Check more on documentation. This is just example
           # It definitely needs more polishing

           return out_arr
       else:
           # This part was there before. That means it needs to be used, but thats up to you. It seems it simply passes result to __array_finalize__
           return super(MyArray, self).__array_wrap__(out_arr,self, context)

    def __array_finalize__(self, from_array):

        if from_array is not None:
            self.foo = getattr(from_array, 'foo', 'foo')

    # Use only if you know what you are doing
    ## This is second solution. Override. Check result, act accordingly
    #def sum(self,*args,**kwargs):
    #    result = super().sum()
    #    if not result.shape:
    #        return result.reshape(-1)[0] 
    #    else:
    #        return result

a = MyArray(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))

print(a.foo)
print(a.sum())
print(a.mean().__class__)
print(a.sum().__class__)
print(np.mean(a).__class__)

>>> foo
>>> 36
>>> <class 'numpy.float64'>
>>> <class 'numpy.int64'>
>>> <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: This solution already breaks is you choose to apply the sum over the columns or rows: a.sum(axis=0) or a.sum(axis=1) returns 36 , not the desired results.

Comment: @b3rt0 Are you downvoting me to get 50? What about instead downvote me, first note the problem? I fixed it and its not broken anymore

Comment: Just check simple cases before posting the answer. Your solution had a major flaw. Hence the downvote.

Comment: I get -2 for downvoting the answer and yet I think it is not a proper answer. But if the -1 is so important for you I undo it.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, I will try to answer, although, I am not 100% sure if the solution has side effects.

You have to specify the `__array_ufunc__` method. By changing the code in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-ufunc-for-ufuncs I achieved the desired results (I believe those were: not wrapping up scalar results as MyArray, is that correct?)

```
class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, foo='foo'):
        self = input_array.view(cls)
        self.foo = foo
        return self

    def __array_finalize__(self, from_array):
        if from_array is not None:
            self.foo = getattr(from_array, 'foo', 'foo')

    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
        args = []
        in_no = []
        for i, input_ in enumerate(inputs):
            if isinstance(input_, MyArray):
                in_no.append(i)
                args.append(input_.view(np.ndarray))
            else:
                args.append(input_)

        outputs = kwargs.pop('out', None)
        out_no = []
        if outputs:
            out_args = []
            for j, output in enumerate(outputs):
                if isinstance(output, MyArray):
                    out_no.append(j)
                    out_args.append(output.view(np.ndarray))
                else:
                    out_args.append(output)
            kwargs['out'] = tuple(out_args)
        else:
            outputs = (None,) * ufunc.nout

        results = super(MyArray, self).__array_ufunc__(ufunc, method,
                                                 *args, **kwargs)
        if results is NotImplemented:
            return NotImplemented

        if method == 'at':
            return

        if ufunc.nout == 1:
            results = (results,) 

        results = tuple((np.asarray(result).view(MyArray)
                         if isinstance(result, np.ndarray) else result)
                         #if output is None else output)
                        for result, output in zip(results, outputs))

        return results[0] if len(results) == 1 else results
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> a = MyArray(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
>>> a
MyArray([[0, 1, 2],
         [3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8]])
>>> 
>>> a.foo
'foo'
>>> a.sum()
36
>>> np.sum(a)
36
>>> print(a.sum())
36 
>>> a.sum().shape
()
```

Comment: "I believe those were: not wrapping up scalar results as MyArray, is that correct?" <- Yes! Thank you for your answer. I'll accept/vote/bounty answers at the end of the bounty period. Also, holy shit, that's a lot of code for such a seemingly simple goal. Maybe some of it can be inherited?

Comment: Happy it works. I agree it is a lot of code... I will try to condense it a bit and update here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert on classes, but playing with the code from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html:

```
import numpy as np

class FooArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(subtype, shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
                strides=None, order=None, foo='Foo'):
        # Create the ndarray instance of our type, given the usual
        # ndarray input arguments.  This will call the standard
        # ndarray constructor, but return an object of our type.
        # It also triggers a call to InfoArray.__array_finalize__
        obj = super(FooArray, subtype).__new__(subtype, shape, dtype,
                                                buffer, offset, strides,
                                                order)
        # set the new 'info' attribute to the value passed
        obj.foo = foo
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.foo = getattr(obj, 'foo', None)

arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
fa = arr.view(FooArray)
print(fa.sum())
```

Edit: after looking further down the page referenced above and playing some more, I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

class RealisticFooArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, foo='Foo'):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        # add the new attribute to the created instance
        obj.foo = foo
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        # see InfoArray.__array_finalize__ for comments
        if obj is None: return
        self.foo = getattr(obj, 'foo', None)

arr = np.arange(9)
fa = RealisticFooArray(arr).reshape(3,3)
print(fa)
print(fa.foo)
print(fa.sum())
print(type(fa))
```

Edit2: Correction to last line of **array_finalize**

Comment: Unfortunately, `FooArray` cannot be initialized via `FooArray(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))`.

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer that method of instantiation as well.  I bet there's a way, but I haven't dug deep enough to find it.

Comment: I just edited my solution.  This is more what you're looking for.

Comment: ...and another edit.  I forgot to check that the attribute foo was working, and learned it wasn't.  Now it works.

Comment: Thank you. `RealisticFooArray` has the same problem. `RealisticFooArray(np.array([1,2,3])).sum()` -> `RealisticFooArray(6)`. You can't see this when you use `print`.